# PHP returns different times with same settings

Tags: php, date

I've used this code on two different servers:

```
var_dump(date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));
var_dump(gmdate("Y-m-d H:i:s"));
var_dump(date_default_timezone_get());
```

Both produces same `date_default_timezone_get` results: `UTC`, but times are different, in first one i got (*PHP version*:  **5.6.17** ):

```
var_dump(date("Y-m-d H:i:s")); // result: 2016-01-18 09:57:45
var_dump(gmdate("Y-m-d H:i:s")); // result: 2016-01-18 09:57:45
```

And the second produces following results (*PHP version*:  **5.4.37** ):

```
var_dump(date("Y-m-d H:i:s")); // result: 2016-01-18 12:29:37
var_dump(gmdate("Y-m-d H:i:s")); // result: 2016-01-18 12:29:37
```

Both PHP configs from `phpinfo()`is the same:

[image]

Maybe it's about server system date or someting?

Comment: Yes its server system date.

Comment: You see that date.timezone setting in your php.ini, the one that has no value...... make sure that it's properly set to the valid timezone that you want to use

Comment: can you check timzone its may be possible that  in one server you set timezone is differ than other